# Electronic States of the (unstable) tetrahedral CrCl4

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I was probing for first order Jahn-Teller instability in the coordination complex CrCl4 (2 electrons in E set). Taking the direct product yields the states A1 + A2 + E, so I took the symmetric and antisymmetric direct products too to see which states represented a singlet and triplet configurations.

To my surprise, the symmetric direct product yields 2A1 + E while the antisymmetric product yields A2 -A1. I believe that I probably made a mistake somewhere (but can’t find it), so did I make a mistake somewhere in my working, or is there an actual meaning behind a negative irreducible representation?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use a calculator for this? A negative irrep shouldn't be possible. Using a [calculator](http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=704&option=4) show whether you made a mistake in determining irreps or counting symmetry elements.

Comment: I’ve tried it for point group Td, and it really does result in -A1.

Comment: than that suggests to me that you have something wrong with how you counted symm elements. As far as I'm aware, for anything in chemistry having negative irreps is unfeasible.

Comment: Could you try and evaluate the direct product when you have the time? I feel like I probably got too rusty and made a mistake somewhere, but can’t find it.

Comment: Based on this [direct product table](https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Reference/Reference_Tables/Group_Theory_Tables/Direct_Product_Tables) the antisymmetric part should be A2.

Comment: There’s actually nothing there for E x E for Td point group, though.

Comment: that's my bad for missing it. I tried to send one with the table easily accessible but didn't see that it was printed poorly. The top row of table 2 is mislabeled, it should be the same order as the first column. But otherwise the table is correct. What you want is labeled B2 x E, but it is actually the correct direct product for E x E. I would have redirected you to the Atkins Direct product table where this is displayed correctly, but I always have trouble linking PDFs from mobile.